# How Long Does Miner Wait To Receive Commission From Transaction Fee?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

I cannot find the answer so please cite a source if you have one: How long does it take when a miner successfully mines a block to receive the commissions from the transactions included in that block? I ask because it's my understanding that the Block Reward isn't offered until 100 blocks have been added on top of the mined block. I think I read that the Transaction Commissions aren't awarded until 6 more blocks are added, but now I can't confirm that. It stands to reason that there would be some sort of lag before commission are paid by the network in case the mined blocked ends up orphaned or stale. So what is the waiting period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction fees are part of the block reward, so miners will be able to spend those transaction fees at the same time that the block reward matures. The network does not distinguish between the block subsidy and the transaction fees when miners receive their reward for a block.

Comment: I so appreciate your knowledge and willingness to share it.